# How to the access the last item of a list returned by a subroutine without copying it into an array first?

Tags: arrays, perl

I'm looking for a computationally less expensive way to access the last item of a list returned by a subroutine (without modifying the subroutine itself).

As I see it what I'm doing below is actually copying the returned list into a named array `@list`, or into an anonymous array `[]`, and then accessing the last value of that array, not directly the last item of the returned list.

Is there any shortcut here? How can I directly access the last item of the returned list?

```
sub range { return 0 .. 10**7 }
```

This takes 0.808 seconds of user time according to GNU `time`:

```
my @array = range();
print pop @array;
```

And here 0.792 seconds:

```
my @array = range();
print $array[$#array], "\n"
```

0.680 seconds:

```
print pop [ range() ]
```

Comment: I think you're a little confused about lists vs. arrays. See [Arrays vs. Lists in Perl: What's the Difference?](http://friedo.com/blog/2013/07/arrays-vs-lists-in-perl)

Comment: This may be premature optimisation though. Check if it actually matters before faffing about.

Comment: @Sobrique I'd be more worried about memory usage than speed in this case.

Comment: Yes, with a mahoosive array, popping the last. But if you've a mahoosive array (and memory iis a concern), I'd be tempted to not use a sub that created (and returned) it in the first place.

Comment: Your test cases are maybe 2x speed improvement in a single operation. That's insignificant, unless you're doing it a lot in your program. And if you are, you really want to better optimise the generate-and-return, not the popping last element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subroutines don't return arrays, they only return lists. But you're correct that

```
my @array = list();
```

copies the values returned by `list()` into an array. If you only care about the last value, you can use a [list slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices):

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use 5.010;

sub range {
    return 0 .. 10**7;
}

my ($last) = ( range() )[-1];
say $last; # 10000000
```

Comment: Nice. Just for the record this takes 0.440 seconds here.

Comment: Be aware that `range()` is called in list context here. Lots of built-in functions have different behavior in list vs. scalar context, e.g. `localtime`.

Comment: The parentheses enclosing `$last` are meant to avoid a list count, right?

Comment: With the parens the RHS is evaluated in list context; without, scalar context. Slices in scalar context return the last item in the slice, so in this case it doesn't make a difference.